# Want ability to save and load the ESRI map in my Application

Tags: dictionary, save, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

We are developing the app. where user can draw object on map and want to save the location and map extent with all drawn graphics on it to the our server using some serialize JSON representation of that state. and when user come afterward by clicking location Item we want to re-render same state with all last graphics we had drawn on it using same serialize JSON object from server. how to achieve this feature in ArcGIS javascript API. do we need to write our own feature layer if yes then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use a feature service to store and serve the data (graphics). You can define and publish a feature service either using a [local ArcGIS for Server installation](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/what-is-a-feature-service-.htm), or in the cloud on [ArcGIS Online](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm).

Once you have a feature service published, you connect to it using an ArcGIS API for JavaScript (JSAPI) [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer.html). See some of the [editing samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#editing) to get an idea of the different ways you can use a FeatureLayer and other modules from the JSAPI to manage data in a feature service.

You can also (optionally) create a [web map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_webmap.html) that references your feature layer as well as defines other map properties like the initial extent, basemap, etc and then have your app load that web map.

As far as persisting other parts of the map state (extent, visible layers, basemap, etc), the JSAPI doesn't currently include a way to serialize those things. Depending on how complex your map is, you might be able just serialize that the bits of that state that you care about into your own custom JSON format and save it to local storage.

I would avoid trying to serialize all aspects of a map's state. This is more complex than it sounds. At v 4.0 the JSAPI is supposed to offer you the capability to serialize a map object into the web map JSON format so that it can be uploaded to Online/Portal. If you need to do that now, you can try and use [cereal](https://github.com/swingley/cereal) as a starting point.